# Is there equivalent for "I'm starving to death" in Portuguese?

Tags: tradução-inglês, expressões-idiomáticas

In English the sentence "I'm starving to death" in the meaning of "I'm very hungry" (rather than of a real pathological condition). Is there an equivalent in Portuguese (using the word 'death')?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No expression with the exact word "death" (*morte*) comes to my mind, but the almost literal translation of the expression in English, i.e.,

> Estou morrendo de fome.

("I'm dying of hunger.") is very common.

Comment: It is the right translation, not literal. death becomes the verb morrer. They swam across the river. Atravessaram o rio nadando.

Comment: I would have said I am dying of hunger was more common in English too than starving to death. We do say I am starving, of course.

Comment: @mdewey To starve to death is a common idiom in English. And dying of hunger can be literal or metaphorical.

Answer (score 7):

From a Portuguese (Portugal) perspective, it is more common to say "*Estou *a* morrer de fome" than "*Estou morrendo de fome*".

In Portugal the gerund has been largely replaced by "a+infinitive".

Examples:
"Estou *a* comer um bolo." – "I'm eating a cookie".
"Estou *a* passar a ferro."  - "I'm ironing clothes".

While in Brazilian Portuguese the main verb comes in the Gerund form, the European standard  uses the Infinitive form preceded by the preposition *a*.

Comment: Welcome to Portuguese SE, tony! Thanks for contributing.